# Why does NASA trust SpaceX for such important tasks being a very young company?

Tags: spacex, nasa

SpaceX was founded by Elon Musk 14 years ago.

Tesla, which was also founded by Elon Musk, has made fabrication mistakes in its PREMIUM cars due to its very young age -- especially when it comes to assembling parts.

Comment: *has fabrication mistakes in its premium cars due to his very young age*  ?? That's a quick conclusion. Please back it up with data.

Comment: ULA was formed in 2006. Why do you think the age of the company has anything to do with the quality of its products?

Comment: @isorian: I rejected your proposed edit. When you edit someone else's question, please don't change its meaning.

Answer (score 7):

NASA does not just 'trust' its suppliers. It audits them to *make sure* the supplier can deliver what it claims. The [contracts for commercial cargo and crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Orbital_Transportation_Services) flights were built around milestones where the supplier had to show (either in audits or via flight tests) that it can deliver.

Answer (score 5):

Because they convinced NASA they could deliver. And they did. For cheaper than their competitors.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of reasons come to mind, one of public policy and one of effectiveness.

As a matter of **public policy**, the US Congress decided to provide (limited) funding in Congressional law for NASA to (begin) to contract with commercial US companies to develop private orbital rocket launch capability.  SpaceX submitted a response to a NASA request for proposals, and SpaceX won the initial competition in 2006. (SpaceX was the top competitor in that competition, and was the first of two companies NASA executed small contracts with; the second company fell out after failing to raise sufficient capital to meet its project plans, and was later replace by Orbital Sciences, now "Orbital ATK")  SpaceX has continued to achieve a large number of project milestones since, including the first orbital launch of a Falcon 9 in 2010.  SpaceX has delivered on its contracted agreements in such a way that NASA has continued to issue more, and more complex, and higher value contracts to SpaceX for the delivery of space transportation services.

As a matter of **effectiveness**, it is often the case that private economic actors will achieve quite different results than state actors.  Leaving political factors aside, and whether this might be a good or bad thing, we can explain that phenomenon economically merely by pointing out that the various players in each world (the SpaceX company vs. various government workers from members of Congress to NASA employees) face a very different set of incentives.

Each entity (state organizations vs. private company organizations) are good at different things.  To take just one example, think about innovation.  How might the design and improvement year-by-year of the personal computer, or the smartphone, be handled differently by each structure given the incentives the various people face in each environment?  Which might do innovation more rapidly and repeatedly over time.  The empirical data show, hands down, if you want innovation, especially rapid and continuous innovation, during the late-20th and early-21st century, private economic actors will deliver much more than state entities.